# Convergence of $ 1+1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How does one use the comparison test to prove that  $ 1+1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \; ...$ converges?

Is the following argument valid?

$\quad 1+1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \; ...$

$< 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \;... $

$= 2 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \;... $

$= \frac{2}{1-1/2} = 4 $

So the series is bounded above and since every term is strictly positive, the sequence of partial sums is monotone increasing and hence the series converges.

Comment: It's almost valid. You should work with the finite partial sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$S=1+1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \; ...$$

$$=\sum_{0\le r<\infty} \left(\frac12\right)^r+\sum_{0\le r<\infty} \left(\frac13\right)^r$$

Using summation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) of Infinite Geometric Series
$$S=\frac1{1-\frac12}+\frac1{1-\frac13}$$

Comment: I was not sure whether summing the two series separately was valid. I will try to prove that summing two convergent series leads to a limit that is the sum of the two separate limits. Thank you.

Comment: @user114924, if Series $S_1,S_2$ are convergent, so will be $a\cdot S_1+b\cdot S_2$ where $a,b$ are finite arbitrary constants

Comment: Just a remark: I think it's also important to justify why a rearrangement of the terms in the series will converge to the same sum.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to prove it converges, and you don't need to find what it converges to, yes, your argument is concise and valid.

Refer to lab bhattacharjee's answer for the actual value it converges to.

Answer (score 0):

Using the root test, we can prove easily,

note that,

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2n]{\frac 1 {2^n}}=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}<1 $$

Hence the convergence.